# Grep for string but ignore commented out items with string

Tags: shell, text-processing, scripting, grep

I'm looking for the words `gmail` or `outlook` in a directory. Although there are some lines commented out with the word `gmail` and `outlook` in it. How can I `grep` for this?

I tried a bunch of things but I imagine it will look something like:

```
grep "^[^#;]" | egrep -i "gmail|outlook" *.ksh  > a.log
```

Comment: Nat's and chaos's answers work with only a single `grep` process, assuming your implementation of grep can use Perl regexps. (Gnu `grep` can, but for example the default `grep` on an OSX machine can't.) To do it in the way you were trying, you'd do `grep "^[^#;]" *.ksh | egrep -i "gmail|outlook" > a.log`, or `grep -v "^[#;]" *.ksh | egrep -i "gmail|outlook" > a.log`.

Answer (score 5):

With `grep`:

```
grep -P '^(?=[\s]*+[^#])[^#]*(gmail|outlook)' file
```

- `-P` activates Perl compatible regular expressions.
- `^(?=...)` defines a capture group which is not part of the pattern (lookahead; a Perl extenstion). The `^` means the start of the line.

  - Inside that group `\s` matches any whitespace character, `*+` matches the whitespace 0 or more times and is greedy (a Perl extension).
  - `[^#]` matches any character which is not a `#`.
- `[^#]*` outside the capture group we again match any character which is not a `#` 0 or more times
- `(gmail|outlook)` finally match `gmail` or `outlook`

---

I made a test file with different examples:

```
$ cat file
# outlook
blah gmail # this should match
# gmail
  # gmail
        # foo
blah outlook # this should match
  outlook blah # gmail - this should match
foobar # gmail
        bar
        another gmail # this should match
```

The output is:

```
blah gmail # this should match
blah outlook # this should match
  outlook blah # gmail - this should match
        another gmail # this should match
```

---

Of course, you can run this on all your `*.ksh` files:

```
grep -P '^(?=[\s]*+[^#])[^#]*(gmail|outlook)' *.ksh  > a.log
```

Answer (score 2):

So you want to search all the `.ksh` files in your current directory for the string `gmail` and `outlook` and exclude lines that start with `#` and write the output to `a.log`.

Okay `grep -P "^(?=[^#])(.*gmail.*|.*outlook.*)" *.ksh > a.log`

Comment: Why not use a negative lookahead assertion? So `^(?!#)(...as before...)`.

Answer (score 1):

What about using:

```
egrep "gmail|outlook" *.ksh | grep -v ^[#]
```

First `grep` gets all lines that contain "gmail" or "outlook", and the second `grep` omits the commented lines

Comment: It will not work when the comment is in the middle of the line. The beginning isn't a comment. For exemple `gmail #anyComment`

Comment: @M4rty You are right, I forgot to add the condition to only check the beginning of the line